# Java 8: How do functional Interfaces list hidden files?

Tags: java

In a Java 8 introduction mini-book, I saw these implementation for listing hidden files:

```
File[] hiddenFiles = mainDirectory.listFiles(f -> f.isHidden());
```

and

```
File[] hiddenFiles = mainDirectory.listFiles(File::isHidden);
```

I checked the docs and it looks like `listFiles` accepts both `FileFilter` or `FilenameFilter` implementation. Both are functional interfaces.

From the Javadocs:

> **Functional Interface:**
>
> This is a functional interface and can therefore be used as the
>   assignment target for a lambda expression or method reference.

**My questions:** What happens in both cases (the expression versus the method reference), and how does Java adjust what I send to `listFiles`?

**What I mean:** In the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/io/File.java#File.listFiles%28java.io.FileFilter%29), I can't find any indication whether `listFiles` checks for a method reference or lambda expression. I understand that Java internally checks and adjust both (lambda or method ref) to become  `FileFilter` or `FilenameFilter` instances, as shown by the lambda expression and how it can be the `accept` method, but what happens internally with `File::isHiiden`? Is it wrapped with some kind of class, or is it transformed into expression such as the first case?

I know I'm kind of lost here, maybe confused, but I hope you could understand pretty much what my questions is.

**Edit:**

I found few useful statements from the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13.2) (I changed a bit):

> Evaluation of a method reference expression is distinct from
>   invocation of the method itself.
>
> At run time, evaluation of a method reference expression is similar to
>   evaluation of a class instance creation expression
>
> The class implements the targeted functional interface type
>
> A new instance of a class with properties(depends on the expression) is
>   allocated and initialized, or an existing instance of a class with the
>   properties below is referenced
>
> The value of a method reference expression is a reference to an
>   instance of a class with the following properties(depends on the
>   expression)

So for example in my case, where I use `File::isHidden`, an object will be created by a class that implements `FileFilter`, `FileFilter` have `accept` method that accepts `File` type objects and calls `isHidden` on those `File` type objects.

Comment: Your source code link is Java 6, try reading the [Java 8](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/io/File.java/) one

Comment: The method gets an implementation of `FileFilter`. It doesn't see how that is a lambda / method reference behind the scenes. http://ideone.com/p4Uwo9 - It looks the same, it's not identical, there is for example no extra class generated at compile time like with real implementations of any interface

Comment: I wouldn’t put too much trust in a book on Java 8 that uses java.io.File for an example instead of `Files.newDirectoryStream(mainDirectory, p -> Files.isHidden(p))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at [JLS 15.27.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.3), "Type of a Lambda Expression", you will know that the lambda expression is simply an expression that can be assigned to a variable of that functional interface (here your lambda is an expression of a type assignable to `FileFilter`. This is because your expression (`File -> boolean`) is *congruent* with the `FileFilter` functional interface, and not the `FilenameFilter` interface.

To answer the second part of your question, there is in fact wrapping in a class, as described in [JLS 15.27.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.4).